# Chip inside a Material Textfield with multilines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So i was using this TagsInput as shared in the link for codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-input-with-chips-0s2j4?from-embed=&file=/src/TagsInput.js

The issue im facing is if there are alot of chips then the chips go out of the text field

What im trying to do is to find a way where i can have like a multiline Textfield so that if chips are too many they go to next line like they do in Autocomplete.

```
export default function TagsInput({ ...props }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { selectedTags, placeholder, tags, ...other } = props;
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedItem(tags);
  }, [tags]);
  useEffect(() => {
    selectedTags(selectedItem);
  }, [selectedItem, selectedTags]);

  function handleKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      const newSelectedItem = [...selectedItem];
      const duplicatedValues = newSelectedItem.indexOf(
        event.target.value.trim()
      );

      if (duplicatedValues !== -1) {
        setInputValue("");
        return;
      }
      if (!event.target.value.replace(/\s/g, "").length) return;

      newSelectedItem.push(event.target.value.trim());
      setSelectedItem(newSelectedItem);
      setInputValue("");
    }
    if (
      selectedItem.length &&
      !inputValue.length &&
      event.key === "Backspace"
    ) {
      setSelectedItem(selectedItem.slice(0, selectedItem.length - 1));
    }
  }
  function handleChange(item) {
    let newSelectedItem = [...selectedItem];
    if (newSelectedItem.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      newSelectedItem = [...newSelectedItem, item];
    }
    setInputValue("");
    setSelectedItem(newSelectedItem);
  }

  const handleDelete = item => () => {
    const newSelectedItem = [...selectedItem];
    newSelectedItem.splice(newSelectedItem.indexOf(item), 1);
    setSelectedItem(newSelectedItem);
  };

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Downshift
        id="downshift-multiple"
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
        selectedItem={selectedItem}
      >
        {({ getInputProps }) => {
          const { onBlur, onChange, onFocus, ...inputProps } = getInputProps({
            onKeyDown: handleKeyDown,
            placeholder
          });
          return (
            <div>
              <TextField
                InputProps={{
                  startAdornment: selectedItem.map(item => (
                    <Chip
                      key={item}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      label={item}
                      className={classes.chip}
                      onDelete={handleDelete(item)}
                    />
                  )),
                  onBlur,
                  onChange: event => {
                    handleInputChange(event);
                    onChange(event);
                  },
                  onFocus
                }}
                {...other}
                {...inputProps}
              />
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Downshift>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
TagsInput.defaultProps = {
  tags: []
};
TagsInput.propTypes = {
  selectedTags: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  tags: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `AutoComplete` to achieve this.
[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiline-autocomplete-with-chips-wiqnzy?file=/src/App.js:110-445)

```
<Autocomplete
  clearIcon={false}
  options={[]}
  freeSolo
  multiple
  renderTags={(value, props) =>
    value.map((option, index) => (
      <Chip label={option} {...props({ index })} />
    ))
  }
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField label="Add Tags" {...params} />}
/>
```